# CloudFoundry manifest.yml with objects as env variables

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml, manifest, cloud-foundry

so I am building a SpringBootApplication and I currently have the following settings in the yml:

```
my:
   caller:
      - id: someId
        url: someUrl
        context: someContext
      - id: someId2
        url: someUrl2
        context: someContext2
```

So basically it's a list of objects (I've created a POJO which has the 3 fields). Those objects are represented as a List in another class which is a @Component and has a @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my") and the List of POJOs is with @NestedConfigurationproperty.
So far everything works perfectly, Spring constructs the objects from the application.yml and fills the List just fine, however I can't simulate this configuration in CloudFoundry. I'm using a different manifest.yml for cloudfoundry, and I'm trying to place this structure in the env part of the manifest but it's not working (Cloudfoundry ignores it).
It looks something like this:

```
env:
   my:
   caller:
      - id: someId
        url: someUrl
        context: someContext
      - id: someId2
        url: someUrl2
        context: someContext2
```

I know with simple lines it works (for example ev_my_caller_id) but that way I can construct only 1 object, not a whole list and I haven't found anything in the CloudFoundry doc on how to construct multiple objects from the manifest.
If anyone has any ideas I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 3):

The `env` block of the Cloud Foundry cli's manifest.yml file has a specific format.  You cannot use an arbitrary structure and expect it to work.

The format is:

`env:
  var_name_1: val_1
  var_name_2: val_2`

See docs for more details -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block

If you set the env variable with the correct name, you can use that to override certain values in Spring.  Thanks to Spring Boot's external configuration support.  Maybe that would be an option for you here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Ex: `MY_PROPERTY=1234` would override `my.property` in application.properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` environment variable mentioned in the [Spring Boot external config link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) that Daniel provided.

In your case, that would like something like this:

```
env:
  SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{ "my": { "caller": [{ "id": "someId", "url": "someUrl", "context": "someContext" }, { "id": "someId2", "url": "someUrl2", "context": "someContext2" }]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can try something like this:

```
env:
  test: '{ whatever complex object/variables }'
```

e.g.

```
env:
  test: '{ variable = value, variable2 = value2 }'
```